# How do I map a target to a source Map field having different parameterized types using MapStruct?

Tags: java, json, dto, mapstruct

I want to use MapStruct to map from my `Car` to `CarDto` objects. The problem is that `Car` and `CarDto` have different parameterized types for their `java.util.Map` field. And that's because I want a simple `Map` key in the DTO since it will be converted to JSON.

The "from" (i.e., domain) classes are:

```
@Data
public class Car {
  private Long id;
  private Map<Group, Option> optionsByGroup; //this needs to be mapped to CarDto's Map<Long,Option>
}

@Data
public class Option {
  private Long id;
  private Car car;
  private String name;
  private Group group;
}

@Data
public class Group {
  private Long id;
  private String name;
}
```

And the "to" (i.e., DTO) classes are:

```
@Data
public class CarDto {
  private Long id;
  private Map<Long, Option> optionsByGroupId; //this needs to be mapped from Car's Map<Group,Option>
}

@Data
public class OptionDto {
  private Long id;
  private String name;
}
```

I have the following mappings:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = OptionMapper.class)
public abstract class CarMapper {

    public abstract CarDto from(Car car);
}

@Mapper(unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE,componentModel = "spring")
public interface OptionMapper {

    OptionDto from(Option option);
}
```

The `Long` key of `optionsByGroupId` should be the id of the `Group` key of `optionsByGroup`. How do I have MapStruct do this mapping?

I could write my own mapping (e.g., using `@AfterMapping`) but can MapStruct do this mapping via `@Mapping` or via some other configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You maybe can use a Qualifier to transform the map to the format you want. So you are going to create a method to extract the Long value from Group and return the Map in the format you need, and that method you will annotate it `@Named('mapToLong')` for example. Then in the method `public abstract CarDto from(Car car);` you need to tell to use the method you create with `@Mapping(source='optionsByGroup', target='optionsByGroupId', qualifiedByName='mapToLong')`

Here the [documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#_combining_qualifiers_with_defaults) for reference.